# How can I use audio signal to actuate relay (or close dry contact)?

Tags: audio, relay, rfid

I have a time clock (prox reader) that has no contact or voltage output - other than a speaker chime.  I need to actuate a turnstile on valid time clock swipe (RFID card).  I'd hoped I could steal the speaker signal to actuate relay...but no luck so far.

Voltage before chime is roughly 200 mV; during chime: ~300 mV.

Is there a way to use/recognize/convert that signal to close a dry contact or generate adequate voltage to trigger relay?

Comment: Can you use a microcontroller?

Comment: Not sure what micro controller is...but willing to learn.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/audio-controlled-relay-circuit

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17228/how-can-i-best-amplify-a-signal-from-my-headphone-jack-to-operate-a-relay-3-32vd

Answer (score 5):

Detecting audio and making a digital line wiggle is pretty easy:

[image]

This circuit keeps Q2 not quite turning on.  Just a little signal thru C1 causes it to turn on at least for part of each cycle, which makes OUT pulse low.  OUT will swing nearly rail to rail and will be a clipped digital signal.  Now that you have a digital signal that goes low regularly when audio is present, you can feed this into a retriggerable one-shot and have the output of that drive a relay or whatever.